# Maximum and minimum involving functional equation.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f$ be continous in $\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x+1)=f(x).$ Prove: $f$ takes on minimum and maximum.

Comment: Hint: try to look at $f$ in $[0,1]$ and remember that $f$ is continuous and $[0,1]$ is a closed interval

Answer (score 1):

A function that satisfies this condition is called a $1$-[periodic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function). For such functions, their behavior is completely described by their restriction to any interval of length 1. Since $f$ is continuous, take its restriction on $[0,1]$. This restriction is a continuous function over a compact set, so it admits a maximum and a minimum value. Can you see how periodicity forces these values to be the maximum and the minimum of $f$ over the entire $\mathbb{R}$?